# Not able to load large 3D obj Files in Unity Webgl

Tags: browser, out-of-memory, heap-memory, unity-webgl

I'm trying to load 3D obj file in webgl project. The obj files with size around 50mb, it is giving an error in the Browser. I referred this [web site](https://forum.unity.com/threads/where-to-change-heap-size.764189/) and used this [script](https://forum.unity.com/attachments/buildwebgl-cs.501419/), which gives us various configurations for a webgl build but that didn't help too.

I'm using [AsImpL](https://github.com/satputerohan/AsImpL) for importing obj file in Unity 2020.1.0a12. I have attached the Screenshot of the Browser Page that is giving the error.

Please let me know if there is a solution for this problem?

[image: Screenshot of Browser error]

Comment: Can you give a link for the OBJ file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zw20HOfeLRpBdzHZ5pPR4P-if4rmRB93/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i've attached the link for the obj file

Comment: The problem is most likely with the loader parsing the file. Any reason why you want to go with OBJ file? Usually OBJ is a text file takes lot of space.

Comment: may i know if there is any better way to ,load 3d OBJ Model, into Webgl ?Thank you

Comment: Im using [AsImpl](https://github.com/satputerohan/AsImpL) library to load the OBJ file into the Webgl project , there was something different that i noticed when i loaded an [OBJ file sized 68mb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QOSDSR99gQDwDiYwN8iG1ext-NM2YHX0/view?usp=sharing) successfully loaded into the project, where as the [OBJ file sized 32mb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QOSDSR99gQDwDiYwN8iG1ext-NM2YHX0/view?usp=sharing) mentioned in above comment didnt load   ? can i please know any better solution for this

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are trying to achieve. The 3D model has a lot of coplanar polygons. And does not need such much triangle count. The mesh can be optimised.

Comment: On the other hand, if what you need is to load the static mesh file, then go for other formats which are compact. Or optimise the mesh heavily.